# how validate a date from a custom validation method?

Tags: jquery

hi i have the following code to validate a date range

HTML:

```
   <div class="form-group">
        <label for="txtLastName">Registration Date:</label>
        <input type="date" class="form-control" id="txtRego" name="txtRego" />
    </div>
```

JS:

```
            var f = $('#f1');//this is the form

            $.validator.addMethod('dateRange', function (value, element) {

                if ((value >= '1/31/2016' && value <= '3/31/2016')) {
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    return false;
                }
            }, 'entered date is out of range');

 f.validate({
                rules: {

                    txtRego: {
                        dateRange: true
                    }
                },
                messages: {

                    txtRego: {
                        dateRange: 'not in range'
                    }
                }
            });
```

but it does not validate the range. why it wont validate date?

Comment: You are comparing ( greater than or less than ) with a string. You need to convert the value to a date object and then do a comparison.

Comment: Use the [momentjs](http://momentjs.com) library to do this for you.

Comment: @DinoMyte if u can that as an answer can give points!

Comment: @FeddrickMoria: Hemnath has already posted the answer. No point answering the same solution. You can go ahead and accept if it works for you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
var f = $('#f1');//this is the form
var startdate = new Date('1/31/2016');
var enddate = new Date('3/31/2016');
$.validator.addMethod('dateRange', function(value, element) {
    var value = new Date( value );
    if ((value >= startdate && value <= enddate)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}, 'entered date is out of range');

f.validate({
    rules : {

        txtRego : {
            dateRange : true
        }
    },
    messages : {

        txtRego : {
            dateRange : 'not in range'
        }
    }
});
```